# Updating a ListFragment from another class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a Class that helps download data and store them in a Content Provider, and I've a ListFragment that loads the data from the provider, when the user login, the data is downloaded and everything works fine, but when there's an update in the data, the class meant to download downloads the data and saves it, but when I call the ListFragment to update, it crashes. Any help would be appreciated, my code is below:

This is the class that downloads the data

```
public class OrderDataRetrieval {

    final Context context;
    ProgressDialog pDiag;

    public OrderDataRetrieval(final Context myContext){
        context = myContext;
    }

    public void getData(String getToken, final Uri uri1, final Uri uri2, final Uri uri3){

        pDiag = new ProgressDialog(context.getApplicationContext());
        pDiag.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDiag.setCancelable(false);
        String order_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json?token=" + getToken + "&contain=nnnnn,mmmm&uuuuu=0";
        //pDiag.show();
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        final Entry entry = cache.get(order_URL);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                order_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //pDiag.dismiss();
                        if (response != null) {
                            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri2, null, null);
                            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri3, null, null);
                            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri1, null, null);
                            Log.d("REPLY", response.toString());
                            handleResponse(response, uri1, uri2, uri3);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //pDiag.dismiss();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    public void handleResponse(JSONObject response, Uri uri1, Uri uri2, Uri uri3){


        try {
            JSONObject respOrd = response.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONObject dataOrd = respOrd.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray ordersArr = dataOrd.getJSONArray("orders");
            Log.d("TEST", uri1.toString());
            Log.d("TAGURL", uri2.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < ordersArr.length(); i++) {

                ContentValues value = new ContentValues(); 
                JSONObject ordItmObj = (JSONObject) ordersArr.get(i);
                final String id = ordItmObj.getString("id");
                value.put("order_id", ordItmObj.getString("id"));
                value.put("source_number", ordItmObj.getString("number"));
                value.put("order_type", ordItmObj.getString("order_type"));
                value.put("order_picked", ordItmObj.getString("picked"));
                value.put("order_delivered", ordItmObj.getString("delivered"));
                value.put("source_code", ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_code"));
                value.put("source_email", ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_email"));
                value.put("source_name", ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_name"));
                value.put("source_phone", ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_phone_number"));
                value.put("source_address", ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_address_line_1") + " " + ordItmObj.getString("source_customer_city"));
                value.put("destination_code", ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_code"));
                value.put("destination_email", ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_email"));
                value.put("destination_name", ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_name"));
                value.put("destination_phone", ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_phone_number"));
                value.put("destination_address", ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_address_line_1") + " " + ordItmObj.getString("destination_customer_city"));
                context.getContentResolver().insert(uri1, value);
                JSONArray ordItem = ordItmObj.getJSONArray("OrderItem");
                for (int j = 0; j < ordItem.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject itm = (JSONObject) ordItem.get(j);
                    ContentValues valueItem = new ContentValues();
                    valueItem.put("order_id", id);
                    valueItem.put("item_name", itm.getString("name"));
                    valueItem.put("item_quantity", itm.getString("quantity"));
                    valueItem.put("item_details", itm.getString("details"));
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(uri2, valueItem);
                }
                JSONArray ordIssues = ordItmObj.getJSONArray("Issue");
                for (int h = 0; h < ordIssues.length(); h++) {
                    JSONObject issues = (JSONObject) ordIssues.get(h);
                    ContentValues valueIssues = new ContentValues();
                    valueIssues.put("order_id", id);
                    valueIssues.put("issue_type", issues.getString("issue_type_id"));
                    valueIssues.put("issue_description", issues.getString("description"));
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(uri3, valueIssues);
                }
            }


Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("RELOAD");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            //pends.getActivity().
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

And below is the ListFragment that needs to be updated, `PendingFragment pends = PendingFragment.getInstance();
            pends.getResults();` when that line is called, it crashes the app

```
    public class PendingFragment extends ListFragment{

        Context activityContext;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private PendingOrderListAdapter listAdapter;
        private List<PendingTrackItem> trackItems;
        SharedPreferences pref;
private BroadcastReceiver myReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getResults();
        }
    };

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(myReciever);
    };
        private static PendingFragment pending;

        public PendingFragment(){

        }

        public static PendingFragment getInstance(){
            if (null == pending) {
                pending = new PendingFragment();
            }
            return pending;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View pending = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_frag, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            return pending;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            ListView list = getListView();

            trackItems = new ArrayList<PendingTrackItem>();
            listAdapter = new PendingOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), trackItems);
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView add_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orderId);
                    TextView orderNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
                    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myId", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    edit.putString("int1", add_id.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderFragmentActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("key1", orderNumber.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });

        }

        public void getResults(){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + getString(R.string.AUTORITY_ORDER) + "/order");
            Log.d("URL PRINT", uri.toString());
            final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, "_id");
            Log.d("CURSOR DATA:", cursor.toString());
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            object.put("destination_address", cursor.getString(0));
                            object.put("destination_code", cursor.getString(1));
                            object.put("destination_email", cursor.getString(2));
                            object.put("destination_name", cursor.getString(3));
                            object.put("destination_phone", cursor.getString(4));
                            object.put("_id", cursor.getString(5));
                            object.put("order_delivered", cursor.getString(6));
                            object.put("order_id", cursor.getString(7));
                            object.put("order_picked", cursor.getString(8));
                            object.put("order_type", cursor.getString(9));
                            object.put("source_address", cursor.getString(10));
                            object.put("source_code", cursor.getString(11));
                            object.put("source_email", cursor.getString(12));
                            object.put("source_name", cursor.getString(13));
                            object.put("source_number", cursor.getString(14));
                            object.put("source_phone", cursor.getString(15));
                            array.put(object);
                            Log.d("ARRAY", String.valueOf(array.length()));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    parseJsonFeed(array);
                    cursor.close();
                    /*FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft  = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ClosedFragment cF = new ClosedFragment();
                    ft.replace(android.R.id.list, cF);
                    ft.commit();
                    cF.getResults();*/
                }

        }

        public void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray jArr){
            Log.d("jsonArr", jArr.toString());
            try {
                trackItems.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject rest = (JSONObject) jArr.get(i);
                    String check = rest.getString("order_delivered");
                    PendingTrackItem item = new PendingTrackItem();
                    String sourceAdrress, destinationAddress;
                    sourceAdrress = rest.getString("source_address");
                    destinationAddress = rest.getString("destination_address");
                    Log.d("ORDER_CHECK", rest.toString());

                    if (check.equals("false")) {
                        item.setId(rest.getString("order_id"));
                        item.setNumber(rest.getString("source_number"));
                        if (sourceAdrress.matches(" ")) {
                            item.setSourceAddress(rest.getString("destination_address"));
                            item.setSourceName(rest.getString("destination_name"));
                        } else if (destinationAddress.matches(" ")) {
                            item.setSourceAddress(rest.getString("source_address"));
                            item.setSourceName(rest.getString("source_name"));
                        } else {
                            item.setSourceAddress(rest.getString("source_address"));
                            item.setSourceName(rest.getString("source_name"));
                        }
                        trackItems.add(item);
                    } 
                }
                //Log.d("ITEm", String.valueOf(trackItems.size()));
                TextView txt =  (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(trackItems.size()));
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
            String getToken = pref.getString("key1", "no data");
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("RELOAD");
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(myReciever, filter);
            getResults();
            //getData(getToken, uri, itemUri, issuesUri);
            super.onResume();
        }
    }
```

The crash report is

```
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723): Process: com.deliveryscience.pod, PID: 9723
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PendingFragment{41f49628} not attached to Activity
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:603)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:625)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.deliveryscience.pod.fragments.PendingFragment.getResults(PendingFragment.java:109)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval.handleResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:122)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval$1.onResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:53)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.deliveryscience.pod.handlers.OrderDataRetrieval$1.onResponse(OrderDataRetrieval.java:1)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
10-08 13:29:34.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9723):     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
```

I am stuck at finding a way to refresh the ListFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps

1) register a  broadcast receiver in ListFragment.

2) from Downloading data class, send a broadcast message with same intent you registered your receiver with.

instead of  below code, use sendBroadcast

```
 PendingFragment pends = PendingFragment.getInstance();
            pends.getResults();
```

3) do the needful update from onReceive of Receiver class.

Alternatively you can use Handler to communicate between Download class and Fragment.

instead of